# How to convert date from one culture to another culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have date with `yy-MMM` format in polish culture (pl-PL) and i want to convert that date in English (en-US)

**Example**

19-maj

**Expected Output**

19-may

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have date as string with yy-MMM format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a string representing a datetime and you want to display the same information but in a different Culture then you could convert that string to a DateTime with the proper CultureInfo, then, once you get a datetime, you could output it in any format you like

```
string input = "19-maj";
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yy-MMM", ci);
string output = dt.ToString("yy-MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, May i know why you using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for convert date to string? It's returning same if i will remove that parameter

Comment: Because that will ensure a proper conversion to the InvariantCulture but if you get the same result with your current locale info then you could remove it (or replace it with whatever culture you need the output